# Run queue using Laradock supervisor

Tags: php, laravel, laradock

I am using laradock to run an application and in this application many queue are executed. I configured the commands in supervisor.d on laradock but they are not executed.

Details: Queues are written to the database, but a "not working" command by supervisor is not running.

I executed the command: "docker-composer stop" , "docker-composer build", "docker-composer build php-worker"  but not working.

My application is in the same structure as laradock

```
-- webserver
    |
    |_blog
    |_laradock
```

My file *.conf in supervisor.d:

```
laradock->php-worker->supervisor->supervisord.d->laravel-worker.conf
```

````
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php blog/artisan queue:work queue=blog --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
startsecs=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
user=root
redirect_stderr=true
```
````

Comment: do u still have this issue ?

Comment: I'm having trouble too even after reading this issue: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1367#issuecomment-514794070

Answer (score 1):

You should put the files into:

`./laradock/supervisord.d/laravel-worker.conf`

and just restart all the docker containers.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error on your worker file

line:

```
command=php blog/artisan queue:work queue=blog --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
```

should be changed to:

```
command=/full/path/to/php /full/path/to/your/blog/artisan queue:work queue=blog --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
```

Change it then restart the docker containers